# Как создать запрос с ASP .NET Core Web App на аналогичный сервер при старте?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, сервер, asp.net-core

Необходимо отправить сообщение с сервера(№1) на сервер(№2) о том что он(№1) запущен и готов обрабатывать запросы.

В каком месте это лучше делать? И возможно ли это? К примеру:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
       //тут сервер еще не готов
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
       //тут уже не ничего не исполниться 
    }
```

Comment: есть идея делать подписку   в месте "тут сервер еще не готов" на опрос готовности сервером(№2) . Но не уверен что оптимально.

Comment: [Running async tasks on app startup in ASP.NET Core](https://andrewlock.net/running-async-tasks-on-app-startup-in-asp-net-core-part-1/) ?

Comment: Если делаю async (public async static Task Main(string[] args)) - показывает ошибку "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изобретать ничего не нужно, [все уже сделано за нас](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-2.2):

Вы можете добавить проверки на готовность (readiness)
И на жизнеспособность (health-checks) грубо говоря: работает сам, и все необходимые для него сервисы, такие как шина сообщений, база данных, другие микросервисы или подсистемы)

Пример использования хорошо расписан в документации, приведу лишь основные моменты:

1. Ставите nuget пакет [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthCheck](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks)
2. Прописываете в Startup.ConfigureServices

```cs
services.AddHealthChecks();
```

3. Добавляете middleware в Startup.Configure:

```cs
app.UseHealthChecks("/health");
```

Теперь при обращении к http://yourdomain.com/health 
будет предоставлена информация о жизнеспособности системы, в котором можно добавить проверку зависимых систем.

Для проверки готовности принимать запросы достаточно добавить

```
app.UseHealthChecks("/ready", new HealthCheckOptions()
{
    // при обращении к http://yourdomain.com/ready будет возвращать HTTP OK 200, если сервис поднялся и работает, но без доп. проверок.
    Predicate = (_) => false
});
```

Проверки в обратную сторону довольно странный кейс, но можно так же реализовать в стартапе, дёрнув какой-нибудь метод сервиса 2.

Comment: позже понял что хотел свой service discovery написать